# How do I change the iOS app launch background to white instead of black?

Tags: ios

How do I change the iOS app launch background to white instead of black?

Im using a transparent png as launch image and thus the background shows through as black.  I know I could make the png include a white background, but I thought id keep the media assets to a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an iOS app is launched, the launch image is displayed full screen while it loads. You have no other options or configuration available.

Basically, you will have to provide a white launch image.

Honestly though, a flat white PNG will have basically the same file size as a transparent one (~20kB), so it doesn't matter what colour you make it. If file size is really such a concern for you, you could try using something like [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) to reduce the size of the image.

---

The [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) state:

> **Generally, design a launch image that is identical to the first screen of the app.**

For a user-friendly and smooth experience, your launch image should look as close to the first screen of your app as possible (obviously excluding text and dynamic content, but including toolbars etc.), so you'd be better off providing an actual image rather than a blank screen.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify the background color of Loading screen. By default it will black.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but an all white background isn't going to increase the size of the assets. I'd go with the quick, simple, and guaranteed solution.